# Map array of integers to value and id for select values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to load the values from my api transform into react-select {value: 1, label: "Tessting" }, i have been successfull with the single select but multi select i'm having trouble with.

```
const get_companys = () => {
    API.get("/companys")
      ...
        r.data = r.data.map(({ id: value, name: label }) => ({ value, label }));
        set_companys(r.data);
      ...
  };

  const get_news_release_categorys = () => {
    API.get("/news_release_categorys")
      ...
        r.data = r.data.map(({ id: value, name: label }) => ({ value, label }));
        set_news_release_categorys(r.data);
      ...
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    get_news_release_categorys();
    get_companys();

    API.get(`/news_release/${props.id}`)
      .then((r) => {
        reset({
          id: r.data.id,
          // Set form value with id ( works )
          company_id: r.data.company_id,
          // Set form with test array of category id's here 
          news_release_categorys: [4, 5, 3],
        });
      })
      .catch((e) => console.log(e));
  }, [props.id, reset]);
```

set_news_release_categorys transformed data/state

```
0: {value: 1, label: "m&a"}
1: {value: 2, label: "drill result"}
2: {value: 3, label: "mineral resource estimate"}
3: {value: 4, label: "feasibility study"}
4: {value: 5, label: "production guidance"}
...
```

This below is working perfectly with single select

```
 {/* Working Correctly */}
      <Controller
        name="company_id"
        rules={{ required: true }}
        control={control}
        render={({ field: { value, onChange } }) => (
          <ReactSelect options={companys} value={companys && companys.find((x) => x.value === value)} onChange={(selected) => onChange(selected.value)} />
        )}
    />
```

Below works ( for selecting and adding categorys/tags ) but does not load and map initial values. If someone could help me out with the correct filter/map/reduce combination to transform `[4,5,3]` into `[{value: 4, label: "feasibility study"},{value: 5, label: "production guidance"},{value: 3, label: "mineral resource estimate"},]`

```
   {/* Multi not loading default "values" */}
      <Controller
        control={control}
        name="news_release_categorys"
        render={({ field: { value, onChange } }) => {
          return <ReactSelect className="basic-multi-select" onChange={(val) => onChange(val.map((c) => c.value))} options={news_release_categorys} isMulti />;
        }}
      />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the single mode, you have correctly set the default value by finding it from the list. In the multiple values mode, all you need to do is to map the values by filtering them from the list.

Single:

```js
   <ReactSelect 
       options={companys} 
       value={companys && companys.find((x) => x.value === value)} 
       onChange={(selected) => onChange(selected.value)} 
   />
```

Multiple:

```js
   <ReactSelect 
       className="basic-multi-select" 
       value={companys && companys.filter((x) => value.includes(x.value))} 
       onChange={(val) => onChange(val.map((c) => c.value))} 
       options={news_release_categorys} 
       isMulti 
   />
```